# "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function" when I add this line of code - console.log(perksTree.slots.unshift())

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function that find an object from a JSON that has an id === `this.match.mainParticipant.stats.perkSubStyle`. This object contains a property called `slots` that is an array and has 4 elements. Each slot has 3 elements which represent runes from a game. If you iterate over the slots and their elements you get this:

[image]

I get the object using this function:

```
secondaryPerks(){
    let perksTree = this.$store.state.summonerRunes.find(value => value.id === this.match.mainParticipant.stats.perkSubStyle);
    console.log(perksTree.slots.unshift())
    return perksTree
}
```

and I iterate and display the icons using this:

```
    <div v-for='runes in this.secondaryPerks().slots'>
        <div v-for='rune in runes.runes'>
            <img :src="'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/' + rune.icon"  alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the problem is that because that perks tree is secondary one, the perks in slot[0] can never be picked because if they were picked, they'd have to be part of the primaryPerks tree. This means there's no point displaying that none of them were selected. For that reason I am trying to remove the first slot[0] element from the array, however, when I try to unshift() it, I get an error:

> "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function"

And I have no clue why. Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think you mean `shift` rather than `unshift`. `unshift` will try to add items to the array rather than removing them. It doesn't actually matter from the perspective of the infinite loop, either method will have the same effect.

You're creating a dependency on the array and then modifying it. Modifying it will trigger a re-render.

Each time the component re-renders it will shift another item onto/out of the array. Even if the call to `shift`/`unshift` doesn't actually change anything it will still count as modifying the array.

Try:

```js
computed: {
  secondaryPerkSlots () {
    const perksTree = this.$store.state.summonerRunes.find(
      value => value.id === this.match.mainParticipant.stats.perkSubStyle
    );

    return perksTree.slots.slice(1)
  }
}
```

with:

```html
<div v-for='runes in secondaryPerkSlots'>
```

That will create a new array containing the same elements as the original array, omitting the first element.

Alternatively you could put the `slice(1)` directly in the template:

```html
<div v-for='runes in secondaryPerks().slots.slice(1)'>
```

Either way I suggest changing the method to a computed property instead. You should also drop the `this` in your template.

Comment: But in my original code, the returned perksTree is an object with properties and one of those properties is the slots property whereas return perksTree.slots.slice(1) returns only the slots array.

Comment: @Bobimaru True. I have updated my answer accordingly though it is difficult for me to know exactly what the best way to structure this is as I don't know how else you might be using that object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few months ago.

I think the main issue is that you perform logic such as `arr.unshift()`(which will **cause** the template to **re-render** in this case) in your **computed property**.

So, imagine this:

```js
const arr1 = [/* ... */];

// This is different
const computedArr = () => {
 return arr.filter(() => { /* ... */ });
};

// Than this
const computedArr = () => {
 const newArr = arr.filter(() => { /* ... */ });

 // Vue cannot allow this without a re-render!
 newArr.unshift();

 return newArr;
};
```

The latter will cause the template to re-render;

### EDIT

**Check the first comment!**

Comment: Neither of your examples would trigger this problem. From the perspective of reactivity there's no difference between them as you're only modifying the array created using `filter` within the same computed property function. Rendering would not have a dependency on that array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Yes, makes sense. If I were to modify like this `arr.unshift()`, it would trigger the problem, because the rendering would have a dependency on `arr`, right?

Comment: Yes and no. It would trigger a re-render but it would only re-render once because the caching of computed properties would avoid any mutation the second time around. Unlike rendering, mutating within a computed property won't invalidate the cached value of that same computed property. Of course, side-effects within computed properties should be avoided altogether rather than trying to pick a path through the nuances. The OP used a method, not a computed property, so there was no caching to break the infinite loop.